# Image splitting in matlab, imcrop does not crop right

Tags: matlab

I have a scenario where i have to split an image into several pieces.
For that I use 2 for loops to make cuts vertically and horizontally.

```
regionHeight = round((1/verticalCuts)*height);
regionWidth = round((1/horizontalCuts)*width);

for i = 0:verticalCuts-1

   verticalPosition = round(((i)/verticalCuts)*height);

   for j = 0:horizontalCuts-1

    horizontalPosition = round(((j)/horizontalCuts)*width);

    imageRegion = imcrop(im,[verticalPosition,horizontalPosition,regionWidth,regionHeight]);
    imshow(imageRegion);
   end
end
```

The first image slice this code produce seems okay, but everything else are not even the given size.The sizes seem random and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Please help me figure find out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: This code works pretty good. The only thing I'd say is that `verticalCuts` is the amount of horizontal cuts and viceversa.... The sizes dont seem random at all for me, the only thing to note here is that the last column may not have the same with, due to rounding

Comment: Removing round had no effect on the problem. But thanks.

Comment: Oh, you should not remove round, im not saying you should! Its juts happens. When you say sizes ar random what you mean? beause I get the rigth sizes.

Comment: By size I meant the resolution of the sliced region. They were weird because I've given incorrect starting point coordinates. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the starting point coordinates. Switching `verticalPosition` and `horizontalPosition` parameters solved the problem.